# Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session Nodejs y Passport

Tags: javascript, nodejs, passport

Hola amigos estoy usando sessiones de passport en NodeJs, pero al intentar usarlo me manda el siguiente error

> Error: Failed to deserialize user out of session

Este es mi código

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

const pool = require('../../db');

const helpers = require('../lib/helpers');

passport.use('local.signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField : 'name',
    passwordField : 'pass',
    passReqToCallback : true
}, async (req,name,pass,done) => {
   //console.log(req.body);
    const newUser = {
        name,
        pass,
        mail: req.body.mail ? req.body.mail : '',
        role: req.body.role ? parseInt(req.body.role) : 1,
        status : 1,
        data : ''
    };


        newUser.pass = await helpers.encryptPass(pass);
        const result = await pool.query('Insert into Users set ?',[newUser]);

        console.log(result);
        newUser.id = result.insertId;
        return done(null,newUser); 

}));


passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null,user.id);

});

passport.deserializeUser( async (id,done) => {
    const rows = pool.query('select * from users where id_user = ?',[id]);
    done(null,rows[0])
});
```

Comment: Hola, veo que usas un callback asíncrono `async`, entonces tu llamada a `pool.query()` a de ser con `await`. Reescribe la linea así: `const rows = await pool.query(...)`. Con eso debería funcionar. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras gracias mau, estuvo increible, si quieres la respuesta, posteala y te la doy. Mil gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Veo que usas un callback asíncrono (`async`), entonces tu llamada a `pool.query()` ha de ser con `await`.
Reescribe la linea así: `const rows = await pool.query(...)`.

Con eso debería funcionar.